# Как правильно сформировать JSON для ASP контроллера?

Tags: c#, ajax, angularjs, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

Есть следующие классы моделей:

```
public class User
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public bool Admin { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Cost { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Picture { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}

public class Order
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public User User { get; set; }
    public Item Item { get; set; }
}
```

Я пытаюсь сформировать запрос следующим образом:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Получаю 500. При этом другие запросы к этому контроллеру проходят успешно.

Вопрос в следующем.

Как должен выглядеть json для POST-запроса для Order?
И в чем может быть ошибка, если не в json`e?

Comment: Так в чем проблема чтобы продебажить и посмотреть что это за ошибка и где она валится?

Comment: вы хотите JSON Ajax запрос принять на стороне сервера?

Answer (score 0):

Если вы хотите на стороне сервера принять Ajax запрос с телом JSON вам надо использовать атрибут `[FromBody]`.

```
public IActionResult MyAction([FromBody]MyObject obj) {
  // ...
}
```

Этот атрибут говорит парсеру что объект надо собирать из тела (Body) запроса.

Подробнее читаем [тут](https://andrewlock.net/model-binding-json-posts-in-asp-net-core/).

Comment: Все верно, так и делаю, все равно ошибка.

Comment: @Cheephs попробуйте ICOllection заменить на массив.